# Writing Junit by using Mockito for batch Update

Tags: junit5

Can please write the JUnit code by using Mockito for the following code :

```
public void writeToNoClaimLeftBehindMMF(List<NoClaimLeftMedicaidMaster> nclmm) throws Exception {
            String query = Queries.NO_CLAIM_LEFT_MMF_INSERT_QUERY;
        MapSqlParameterSource[] params = new MapSqlParameterSource[nclmm. Size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < nclmm. Size(); i++) {
    
                    params[i] = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                            .addValue("envId", nclmm.get(i).getENV_ID());
                mysqlJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exact behaviour of `writeToNoClaimLeftBehindMMF` you are trying to test. Assuming that you want to mock your `mysqlJdbcTemplate` instance, you will have to inject the mock as a class constructor argument and the test code would be something like this:

```
@Test
public void whenEmptyListIsPassed_thenWriteToNoClaimLeftBehindMMFGoesBlahBlah() {
    // Given
    var mockJdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
    when(mockJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(...,...)).thenReturn(whatever);
    var systemUnderTest = new WhateverYourClassIsCalled(mockJdbcTemplate);

    // When
    systemUnderTest.writeToNoClaimLeftBehindMMF(List.of());

    // Then
    assertTrue(whatever you're testing);
}
```

See https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/index.html

Comment: Above code behavior was to insert multiple records into Data base

Comment: In that case, instead of `when(mockJdbcTemplate,...` use `verify(mockJdbcTemplate).batchUpdate` in your assertions section.